# How can I request a client certificate only from a particular CA

Tags: iis, ssl, ctl

Is it possible to request client certificates issued only by a particular CA (Certificate Authority)?
The site is using IIS 7.5, and we have client certificates assigned to users following this article - http://ondrej.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/iis-7-and-client-certificates/.
CTL does not seem to have any effect on this because the server will always advertise all acceptable CA names, regardless if they are in the CTL or not.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh_singh/archive/2007/12/07/certificate-trust-list-not-being-honored-by-iis-5-0-6-0-7-0.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Run MMC as an Administrator on the server.
- Add the Certificates Add-in, selecting the Computer account.
- In each of the sub-folders, for each of the certificates you DO NOT want to be included:

  - If the Intended Purpose has  or contains Client Authentication:

    - Right-click on the certificate
    - Make sure "Enable only the following purposes" is selected
    - Uncheck "Client Authentication"
    - Click OK.

I had to do this for over 400 certificates on two servers... twice (because GPOs overwrote my settings).